# How to setup and delete a timer in my case?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to delete a timer from a function

I have something like the following

```
main.prototype.setupBtnEvent= function(){
             var instance = this;


        $('#btn').on('click', function(){

            clearTimeout(instance.timer);

          //if there is a timer running then clear the timer, show the content and delete the     
          //timer reference
                if (instance.timer) {
                    delete instance.timer
                    clearTimeout(instance.timer);
                    instance.callFun();
                    return;
                }

                instance.timer = setTimeout(function () {
                    delete instance.timer
                    instance.callFun();
                }, 5000);
       })
}

main.prototype.callFun= function(btnID){
    var message = $('.message');
           if (true)  //I put true here to make sure it's always true in my test case.
                delete this.timer  //I want to kill the 5 sec timer here. Not working
                clearTimeout(this.timer);
            }else{
               //do other things..
            }
}
```

I can't seem to kill the Timeout during the `callFun`. Is there anyway to do this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are deleting the property (twice even) that contains the timer before you try to use it to stop the timer.

You have to stop the timer before you delete the property:

```
clearTimeout(this.timer);
delete this.timer;
```

Also, don't delete the property before calling the `callFun` method.

Comment: I just swap the clearTimeout and delete this.timer and it still the same..+1 though.

Comment: @FlyingCat: As I mentioned, you have code before calling the function that also removes the property, you have to remove those also. Also, you have code outside the function that also attempts to stop the timer, so you have to decide where to do different things so that you don't do it in several places, in different ways, in the wrong order.

Comment: Thanks Guffa! I got it now.

Answer (score 1):

```
var alarm = {
  remind: function(aMessage) {
    alert(aMessage);
    delete this.timeoutID;
  },

  setup: function() {
    this.cancel();
    var self = this;
    this.timeoutID = window.setTimeout(function(msg) {self.remind(msg);}, 1000, "Wake up!");
  },

  cancel: function() {
    if(typeof this.timeoutID == "number") {

      window.clearTimeout(this.timeoutID);
      delete this.timeoutID;
    }
  }
};
window.onclick = function() { alarm.setup() };
```

sweet example. from mozilla https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.clearTimeout

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to clear a timer.  When set, timers return as a number type.  To clear, I just set it to null.

In this example, because 'this' is not available by the time setTimeout function executes, I had to borrow a solution from MDN for setting up a new setTimeout function that will execute immediately at the time of the call and capture the value of 'this' to a variable by closure.

```
var nativeST = window.setTimeout;

newTimeout = function (callback, delay) {
    var that = this;
    return nativeST(function (){callback.call(that);}, delay);
};

$(".btn").click(function () {
    if (typeof this.timerId === "number") {
        clearTimer.call(this);
    } else {
        this.style.color = "#ff0000";
        this.timerId = newTimeout.call(this, clearTimer, 5000);
    }
});

function clearTimer() {
    clearTimeout(this.timerId);
    this.timerId = null;
    this.style.color = "#0000CC";
}
```

See the example in [this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/csrow/5gRwD/3/)  Yoy can click on a button to start the timer for that button.  Before timer expires, you can turn it off by clicking on the button again.  The timer is set to expire in 5 seconds.  You can have multiple timers going on at the same time.